# Fullscreen GTK Box should only fullscreen webkit2gtk window, but fullscreens whole app instead

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3, webkitgtk, gtk-rs

I am attempting to make a Webkit2gtk browser in Rust using WebKit2Gtk-rs. When the WebView attempts to go into fullscreen, it makes the entire application fullscreen, including stuff outside the webview. [screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMtjR.png)

What I am doing is creating a GTK Box then stuffing the two Gtk Buttons into it, along with the Webkit2Gtk WebView.
Main Window -> Gtk Box -> Button1, Button2, WebView.
I would like for only that one element, WebView to go fullscreen.

Source code for the relevant file can be found [here.](https://github.com/moon-laboratories/murasaki/blob/master/src/main.rs)

Comment: Couldn't you hide all the controls that are not your WebView?

Comment: Could, but cannot figure out how to get the status of fullscreen, as in, getting a boolean of whether the window is in fullscreen (true) or not (false).

Comment: Not sure but I think there are events with `connect_enter_fullscreen`  and `connect_leave_fullscreen` to get the necessary notifications.